tempdisagg for future disaggregation with denton
I have monthly time series for the year 2021-2023 and quarterly time series for the year 2021-2024. I thought of using denton method to train the model for the period 2021-2023 by using inside the td function
quarterly_series~0+monthly_series

How can I use the trained model to disaggregate 2024 values?
